# I'm having a problem with the blog post edit button of the Admin panel I made with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an admin panel using React.js. I want to be able to view and edit the blog posts on the site from here. For this, I added a button to the table element where the data comes from. This button triggers the modal from react-strap. However, when this modal is opened, I can only get the data of the post at the bottom of the table. I called the modal inside the map function where I brought the data, by sending the ID value of each Blog post, so that how many data there are on the page, the number of modal renders would be. However, when I click the edit button, all of the modals are triggered. How can I solve this?

I leave the codes of the Blog page I am trying to process:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Table, Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';



export default class Blog extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getBlogPosts();
      
    }

    state = {
        blogPosts: [],
        columns: [
            { name: 'Header', selector: 'header' },
            { name: 'Description', selector: 'description' },
            { name: 'Keywords', selector: 'keywords' },
            { name: 'Body', selector: 'body' },
            { name: 'Create Time', selector: 'createdAt' }
        ],
        modal: false
    }

    toggle = (event) => {
        this.setState({ modal: this.state.modal == false ? true : false });
    }

    getBlogPosts = () => {

        fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/blog")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => { console.log(response); return response; })
            .then((response) => this.setState({
                blogPosts: response.data
            }));
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                {this.state.blogPosts.map(posts=>
                  
                  <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} id={posts._id} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                      <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
                      <ModalBody>
                          {posts.title}
                          </ModalBody>
                      <ModalFooter>
                          <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
                          <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                      </ModalFooter>
                  </Modal>
             
                )}
                
                <Table striped className="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Tag</th>
                            <th>Operations</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> 
                        {this.state.blogPosts.map(post =>
                            <tr key={post._id} >
                                <td> {post.title} </td>
                                <td> {post.description} </td>
                                <td> {post.category} </td>
                                <td> {post.tag} </td>
                                <td> <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}><FaIcons.FaEdit/></Button></td>
                            </tr>

                        )}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Tag</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </Table>

            </Container>

        )
    }
}
```

Previously, I converted the button element to `<a>` element and passed each ID value to the `<a>` element's href attribute. However, the result was bad again.

Comment: Maybe something related to the row key.

Comment: You fetch statement is returning an array of how many elements? I think there are multiple blog posts being returned

Comment: @Ashu It returns 11 posts for now.

Comment: 11 modals being triggered then?

Comment: Right. However, they are not triggered to Open. I assigned the id values ​​of the posts as their id values ​​as well. So yes, it turns 11, but they wait unopened.

Comment: How do you know which id is selected to be opened? I don't see any code for that    <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal}  isOpen is true for every element, ie. for each blog post

Comment: When I click the button, the onClick event is triggered and the toggle function I wrote above works and changes the state named modal. Every modal reads this here. Modal state initial value: false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to toggle modal for a particular ID of blog post only and not every blog post, Modify you table row like this

```
<tr key={post._id} >
    <td> {post.title} </td>
    <td> {post.description} </td>
    <td> {post.category} </td>
    <td> {post.tag} </td>
    {/** Note the toggle function **/
    <td> <Button color="primary" onClick={() => this.toggle(post._id)}><FaIcons.FaEdit/></Button></td>
</tr>
```

In your toggle function

```
 // note the id param
 toggle = (id) => {
     this.setState({ modal: this.state.modal == false ? true : false, id }); // set the id of the blog post in state
 }
```

In your Modal only open the modal for which the id matches

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal && (this.state.id === posts.id)} id={posts._id} toggle={() => this.toggle(posts.id)} className={this.props.className}>
    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
        {posts.title}
        </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
    </ModalFooter>
</Modal>
```

I hope you get the idea.